# Correct way to set ScrollViewer (for vertical scrolling) on a WPF Frame?

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, webbrowser-control, frame, scrollviewer

does anyone know the difference between defining a vertical scrollbar on a frame like this:

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Frame Name="Frame1"
                   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

or like this:

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
            <Frame Name="Frame1"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

This frame is nested in a WebBrowser control and setting it the first way correctly displays the vertical scrollbar and is only visible when it needs to scroll (auto). When I set it the second way the vertical scrollbar works but is always visible even when it does not need to scroll (visible).

I am going to use the 1st option because it meets my needs, but I don't want to be surprised down the road if I am setting it incorrectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you use `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` or `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` attached property it has no effect with Frame.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="225.667,-4,0,296.939" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="221.667">
        <Frame Content="Frame" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Source="UserControl2.xaml" Background="#FFDE5454"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In example above I used both `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` attached properties. outcome of that code is the exact opposite of what you would expect. There is no `HorizontalScrollBar` visible... and you can still see `VerticalScrollBar`.

So that's why this is what you should use

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Frame Name="Frame1" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

When you try this for example with ListBox then result will be different.

This is the result of following code:

[image]

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="225.667,0,0,12.761" Height="280.178" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="221.667">
        <ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Background="Orange" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" DisplayMemberPath="Property1" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

That's because those attached properties now affect ScrollViewer within `ListBox` and not parent `ScrollViewer` as you may expect.

So from this little experiment I assume that `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` attached property is meant for cases where you want to be able to affect `ScrollViewer` which exists within Control's template and not parent `ScrollViewer`. So I think it does not work for example as `DockPanel.Dock` which takes effect on parent `DockPanel`.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps!