# WPF control with Rich Text, No Word Wrap, and Selectable text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a control that is able to select the text displayed inside (read only) but I also need to be able to format the text with Bold and Italics because it's a journal citation.  Furthermore, I'd like the control to be able to size according to the text or content(stretch).  Here's an example:

*Child and Family Behavior Therapy* **26.1** (2004).

The closest I can get is a `RichTextBox` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368047/c-wpf-disable-text-wrap-of-richtextbox) example.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable) `TextBlock` example is also close, but does not allow for font styling in-line (bold, italics, etc..).

**Current RichTextBox solution**

```
    richTextBox1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    richTextBox1.Document.PageWidth = 1000;
```

**Why this doesn't work**: Journals can have long names and with the addition a description it's easy to reach the end of the Page, causing the content to wrap anyway.  Conversely,  a short-named journal that has no description still has a scroll bar leading to a ton of white space.

**Current TextBlock/TextBox solution**

```
    <TextBox Background="Transparent"
     BorderThickness="0"
     Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"
     IsReadOnly="True"
     TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
```

**Why this doesn't work**: I either use the default `TextBlock` and am unable to select the text (The user should be able to copy-paste), or use this `TextBox` binding and lose the styling functionality.

I'm still pretty new to WPF, and have minimal knowledge on how to edit some controls, such as buttons using `OverridesDefaultStyle`, `ControlTemplate` etc..  I just can't seem to find a control that has the three properties I need, or a way a control can be customized to do what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: "(as of July 2015): VS2015 RC allows wordwrap = false"
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1369184/3964654

Comment: If you need no word wrap then why in the world do you have TextWrapping="Wrap" ?

Comment: Thank you Empereur Aiman, I have actually seen this, but What is RC?  I'm using VS2015 and I've looked for a "wordwrap" property on all three controls and it's not recognized.

Comment: Frisbee, That's an example from a separate question that I was using as reference.  If I were to implement it, I would set it to No Wrap.  I will change to avoid further confusion, I apologize.

Comment: Look the the FlowDocument viewer controls.  If you can do it in XAML then you can do inline formatting with TextBox.

Comment: I'm downloading VS2015 Update 1 RC via https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx but it's still installing and I'm at the end of my day, so I will respond next week when I get a chance to try it out

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Even after updating VS 2015 , I don't understand where to find  "wordwrap = false" ... I've searched documents, flowdocuments, viewers, none of them have the property, in XAML or otherwise. I feel dumb, like I'm missing something really obvious, but in any case, thank you both for help.

Comment: I couldn't find it either. Maybe you could clarify with the author of that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a custom `TextBlock`. `RichTextBox` seems overkill.

1) Scroll and sizing

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
      <ns:SelectableTextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" x:Name="stb" TextSelected="stb_TextSelected"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This ensures the presence of the scroll bar for longer texts and its' absence for shorter ones. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054824/correct-way-to-set-scrollviewer-for-vertical-scrolling-on-a-wpf-frame).

2) Selection and copy/paste. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136435/any-way-to-make-a-wpf-textblock-selectable), and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32870521/2239678). [This piece of code on Rextester](http://rextester.com/VNWKGO53977) represents a modification to that example, a custom selectable `TextBlock` with selection highlighting that goes back and forth.

3) Styling and binding `InlineCollection`. Various ways of binding your citation model to `TextBlock.Inlines`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263055/formatting-text-in-a-textblock), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines).

Comment: This worked pretty well, Thanks!  The Rextester example was close to what I needed, though I tweaked it so the text stays selected and doesn't auto-copy on select.